# Question about Kubo formula for conductivity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

The kubo formula for conductivity is
$$
\sigma^{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',\omega)=\frac{ie^{2}}{\omega}\Pi_{\alpha\beta}^{R}\left(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}^{\prime},\omega\right)+\frac{ie^{2}}{m\omega}n(\mathbf{r})\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\delta^{\alpha\beta}
$$
which is a response function between current densit and external electric field
$$
J_{e}^{\alpha}(\mathbf{r},\omega)=\int d\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\sigma^{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',\omega)E^{\beta}\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime},\omega\right)
$$

The first part is a current-current correlation operator
$$
\Pi_{\alpha\beta}^{R}\left(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}^{\prime},t-t^{\prime}\right)\equiv C_{J_{0}^{\alpha}(\mathbf{r}),J_{0}^{\beta}(\mathbf{r}')}(t)$$

The conductance $G(x,x')$, defined to be the response between current and E field
$$
I_{e}(\xi)=\lim _{\omega \rightarrow 0} \int d \xi^{\prime} \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{i e^{2}}{\omega} C_{I(\xi) I\left(\xi^{\prime}\right)}^{R}(\omega)\right] E\left(\xi^{\prime}\right) \equiv \int d \xi^{\prime} G\left(\xi, \xi^{\prime}\right) E\left(\xi^{\prime}\right)
$$
is
$$
G(x,x')=\lim _{\omega \rightarrow 0}\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{i e^{2}}{\omega} C_{I(x) I\left(x^{\prime}\right)}^{R}(\omega)\right]
$$

which seems to be unrelated to the second part
$$
\frac{i e^{2}}{m \omega} n(\mathbf{r}) \delta\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right) \delta^{\alpha \beta}
$$
and has to take a real part also. I'm having trouble understanding the derivation for conductance from conductivity. Can anyone explain?